# Generating a custom json file with user inputs

Tags: python

I need a json file in this order as i have to keep changing the json values.
This is a sample file i want to generate

1.control_file 
Also the location name tag in the json should be enclosed in "","" format
which i need help with.

```
{
 "user": "dex",
 "issue_no": "test_tkt",
 "start_date": "2017-07-01",
 "end_date": "2017-07-01",
 "geo-ids": [627,438,360],
 "location_names": [
    "India.v1.2a_Final",
    "China.v2.3a_setup",
    "Hongkong.4a"
 ]
}
```

Below is the code i wrote.
The expected output

```
import json
import os


filename = input("Enter the file name: ")
user = input("Enter the user name: ")
ticket = input("Enter the ticket id: ")
start_date = input("Enter the start date: ")
end_date = input("Enter the end date: ")

test_list=[]
input_list=input("enter the exp names: ")
exports = input_list.split(",")
for names in exports:
        demo = test_list.append(names)
        print(demo)


if not os.path.splitext(filename)[1]:
    filename += ".txt"


with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump({
        "user": user,
        "ticket": ticket,
        "start_date": start_date,
        "end_date" : end_date,
        "location_names" : [demo]
      }, f, indent=4)


print("JSON saved to file {}".format(os.path.abspath(filename)))
```

output i get

```
{
    "user": "dex",
    "ticket": "test_tkt",
    "start_date": "2017-07-01",
    "end_date": "2017-07-01",
    "location_names": [
        None
        None
        None
    ]
}
```

Output i want:

```
{
 "user": "dex",
 "issue_no": "test_tkt",
 "start_date": "2017-07-01",
 "end_date": "2017-07-01",
 "location_names": [
    "India.v1.2a_Final",
    "China.v2.3a_setup",
    "Hongkong.4a"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the return value of `test_list.append()` to the variable `demo`, but that will always be None because `append()` doesn't return anything.

Since `test_list` contains the list of names, you should use that as the value and get rid of the `demo` variable:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump({
        "user": user,
        "ticket": ticket,
        "start_date": start_date,
        "end_date" : end_date,
        "location_names" : test_list  # Use test_list
      }, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
json.dump({
    "user": user,
    "ticket": ticket,
    "start_date": start_date,
    "end_date" : end_date,
    "location_names" : [item for item in demo]
  }, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: ```Enter the file name: test3
Enter the user name: dex
Enter the ticket id: LIN-0000
Enter the start date: 2017-07-01
Enter the end date: 2017-07-01
enter the exp names: India.v1.2a_Final,China.v2.3a_setup,Hongkong.4a"
 ]None
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dex\eclipse-workspace\PythonTest\src\SamplePrac\Custom_json.py", line 44, in <module>
    "export_names" : [item for item in demo]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable ```   Getting this error